# converting logic tests into try statements (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to convert some code into a try statement but I can't seem to get anything working.

Here is my code in pseudo code:

```
start
run function

check for user input ('Would you like to test another variable? (y/n) ')

if: yes ('y') restart from top 
elif: no ('n') exit program (loop is at end of program)
else: return an error saying that the input is invalid.
```

And here is my code (which works) in python 3.4

```
run = True
while run == True:

    spuriousCorrelate(directory)

    cont = True

    while cont == True:
        choice = input('Would you like to test another variable? (y/n) ')
        if choice == 'y':
            cont = False
        elif choice == 'n':
            run = False
            cont = False
        else:
            print('This is not a valid answer please try again.')
            run = True
            cont = True
```

Now what is the proper way for me to convert this into a try statement or to neaten my code somewhat?

This isn't a copy of the mentioned referenced post as I am trying to manage two nested statements rather than only get the correct answer.

Comment: Why does that need to be expressed as `try..except` blocks? It seems fine as it is.

Comment: I just though it would be neater, also I'm still trying to learn and part of that process is trying to find alternate ways of doing things.

Comment: In general your exceptions should be **exceptional**. There is some overhead to them, so for normal code flow prefer logic statements.

Comment: Ok so as a general case I will try to avoid try...except blocks and focus on logic statements. =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your code neater, you should consider having

`while run:`

instead of

`while run == True:`

and also remove the last two lines, because setting `run` and `cont` to `True` again isn't necessary (their value didn't change).

Furthermore, I think that a `try - except` block would be useful in the case of an integer input, for example:

```
num = input("Please enter an integer: ")
try:
    num = int(num)
except ValueError:
    print("Error,", num, "is not a number.")
```

In your case though I think it's better to stick with `if - elif - else` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok so as a general case I will try to avoid try...except blocks

Don't do this. Use the right tool for the job.

Use `raise` to signal that your code can't (or shouldn't) deal with the scenario.
Use `try-except` to process that *signal*.

> Now what is the proper way for me to convert this into a try statement?

Don't convert.
You don't have anything that `raise`s in your code, so there is no point of `try-except`.

> What is the proper way to neaten my code somewhat?

Get rid of your flag variables (`run`, `cont`). You have `break`, use it!
<sub>This is prefered way of imlementing `do-while`, as Python docs says; unfortunately, I cannot find it to link it right now.</sub>
<sup>If someone finds it, feel free to edit my answer to include it.</sup>

```
def main()
    while True: # while user wants to test variables
        spuriousCorrelate(directory) # or whatever your program is doing
        while True: # while not received valid answer
            choice = input('Would you like to test another variable? (y/n) ')
            if choice == 'y':
                break  # let's test next variable
            elif choice == 'n':
                return # no more testing, exit whole program
            else:
                print('This is not a valid answer please try again.')
```

Comment: The problem I have is distinguishing between which while statement to break, for example if  choice = y then I want to break only the nested one, if choice = n then I want to break both and else I would like to break none.